# Why do we put absolute brackets for ln?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, education

When writing out the final answer in $\ln$ form, why is it necessary to put absolute brackets? How does it affect the answer?

I have this answer of $-3\ln|\frac{3+\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x}|$, but why does it suddenly become

$3\ln|\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}-3}{x}|$?

Comment: What's the ln of a negative number?

Comment: the ln of a negative number is undefined right? because ln's domain is from (0 to infitity).

Comment: so, is it because of its domain that we have to put absolute values signs around the function?

Comment: That and the fact that $\int_a^b \frac 1x dx = \ln|b|-\ln|a|$ even when $a, b \lt 0$.

Comment: @Bye_World: We don't "use absolute value because the domain is only the positive reals". Otherwise every time we use "sqrt" we ought to put absolute values inside! Your last reason is the correct one when we are doing real-valued integrals, but we will have to **not take absolute value when doing complex-valued integrals**.

Answer (score 8):

In this case it's exactly the same:
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{3+\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x}\right|^{\!-1}
&=
\left|\frac{x}{3+\sqrt{9-x^2}}\right|\\[2ex]
&=
\left|\frac{x}{3+\sqrt{9-x^2}}\frac{3-\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3-\sqrt{9-x^2}}\right|\\[2ex]
&=\left|\frac{x(3-\sqrt{9-x^2})}{9-9+x^2}\right|\\[2ex]
&=\left|\frac{3-\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x}\right|\\[2ex]
&=\left|\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}-3}{x}\right|
\end{align}
Thus
$$
-3\log\left|\frac{3+\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x}\right|=
3\log\left|\frac{3+\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x}\right|^{\!-1}=
3\log\left|\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}-3}{x}\right|
$$

Why putting the absolute value when writing
$$
\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\log|x|+c
$$
and not leaving just $x$? Because this works independently whether the interval where the integral is done is a subset of $(-\infty,0)$ or of $(0,\infty)$. However, one should always recall that such a notation has a meaning only if the integrand is considered defined on an interval.